# Bootstrap 3.3.2 - fire JS when content of collapse is visible

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap 3 "collapse" to show and hide some content in one column and have another column that needs to maintain the same height as the column with the collapsible content.

In searching for a method to have the two columns maintain the same height I found a reference to this scrip by SAM152:  https://github.com/Sam152/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows

This works great for setting the column height on page load, when the content is collapsed.

Here is a sample of the "Collapse" - there are multiples of these on the page.

```
<div class="collapse-item">
<a class="collapse-text collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseAbout" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseAbout">About 
</a>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseAbout">
    <div>
        <p>Blah, blah, blah...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center gtButton">
        <a class="gtButton" href="/About.aspx">LEARN MORE</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This script, below, fires when the ".collapse-text" item is clicked.  I am using the CSS class due to there being a number of these on the page.  However, as expected, since the collapsed content is not actually showing yet with the "click" event, the script is not adjusting the column heights as needed.  It pretty much works in reverse.  Expands the column when clicking to collapse and shrinks the column when clicking to expand (depending one what was visible when clicked).

```
$('.collapse-text').on("click", function () {
            $('.equalHeight').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
        });
```

I have searched around and looked at a number of solutions and not been successful at implementing any of them.

Basically, what I am looking to do is call "$('.equalHeight').responsiveEqualHeightGrid();
" when the content visibility changes - not call it when the action that causes it to show or not show is clicked.

Any help is appreciated - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing your Jquery plugin for equal height after collapse content gets visible, using event of collapse "**shown.bs.collapse**"

```
$('.collapse-text').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  // Initialize here
})
```

Comment: This, with a slight edit, worked. I had to switch the ".collapse-text" to ".collapse", the style of the content to be shown - I may rename my styles here as they are confusing. :)

I also added a second one using the event of collapse "hidden.bs.collapse".  This one shrinks the columns back down on the content being hidden.

All of this does make the page jump a little bit, but it does what I asked for and I will have to see if once I get a whole bunch of content loaded if this becomes an issue or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.collapse-text').on("click", function () {
        $('.equalHeight').responsiveEqualHeightGrid(2);
    });
```

where 2 would be number of columns.

```
$('.group-of-elements').equalHeightGrid(n); // Where n is the number of columns.
```

Comment: I am not sure what this would do - the called function does work fine - it is about when it is called.